# Custom UITableViewCell not properly hiding views

Tags: iphone, uitableview, drawrect

I am using apple's custom table view cell code and modifying the drawRect code within the cell's view to look like I want it to.  I've changed it to have some UILabels as well as a UIProgressView.

If the data the cell is being built on doesn't have a certain field, I want the UIProgressView to be hidden.  This works for a little while, but when a cell gets requeued from scrolling, the progress view will start displaying again, even when I set it to hidden = YES.  I've tried just not creating the ProgressView unless the data was there and that didn't work either.

I thought the answer was in the [self setNeedsDisplay] but that doesn't seem to help.

Here is the code for the progressview from drawRect that continues to be displayed:

```
UIProgressView *c1Progress = [[UIProgressView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 70.0, 280.0, 12.0)];   
float iProgress = (value / target);
c1Progress.progress = iProgress;
if (!dataExists) {
    c1Progress.hidden = YES;
}
[self addSubview:c1Progress];
[c1Progress release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't want this code in `drawRect`. You should alloc/init your UIProgressView and add it as a subview in your UITableViewCell subclass `init` method (and be sure to release it in `dealloc`).

The logic for setting `c1Progress.progress` and `c1Progress.hidden` should go in some method that is only called when `value`, `target`, or `dataExists` changes.  If you have a setter method for the data/value in question, that would be a good place for it.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  I moved c1Progress to a class variable, instantiated it in the init method and set the values in the data setter method.  This is my first attempt at custom tableviewcell programming and I want to make sure I'm doing it right so I have nicely scrolling tables!

Answer (score 1):

check dataExists's value...  and print it in NSLog and if this piece of code execute every time... remove this from drawRect... initialize and release it only once...

Comment: dataExists's value is properly set and the code for setting hidden=YES does run.  I put a breakpoint on it and it goes through as expected.